# Getting the Powershell error cannot reference subnets from different virtual networks on UpdateAzureRm-Vmss

Tags: azure, powershell, nic

I am trying to add a second network adapter to an Azure Virtual machine scale set.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


$vnetname = "conf-virtual-network-interlink"

$loc = "West Europe"

$backendSubnetName = "default"

$backendSubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

echo "backendSubnetConfig: "$backendSubnetConfig

$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceName $vnetname -Location $loc -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -Subnet $backendSubnetConfig -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

echo "vnet: "$vnet

$subnetId = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id

echo "subnetId: "$subnetId

$ipCfg = New-AzureRmVmssIPConfig -Name 'eth1' -SubnetId $subnetId 

echo "ipCfg: "$ipCfg

$backendSubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet

echo "backendSubnet: "$backendSubnet

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter -VMScaleSetName confcluster

echo "vmss: "$vmss

Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name $backendSubnet -Primary $false -IPConfiguration $ipCfg -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -Name "confcluster" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

But I am getting the error message:

> Update-AzureRmVmss : VM scale set
>   /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP-CONF
>   LUENCE-JIRA-DATACENTER/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/confcluster
>   cannot reference subnets /subscr
>   iptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter/providers/Microsof
>   t.Network/virtualNetworks/confvnet/subnets/confclustersubnet,/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resour
>   ceGroups/resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/conf-virtual-network-inte
>   rlink/subnets/default from different virtual networks. ErrorCode:
>   VMScaleSetCannotReferenceSubnetsFromDifferentVirtualNetworks
>   ErrorMessage: VM scale set
>   /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP-CONFLUENCE-
>   JIRA-DATACENTER/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/confcluster
>   cannot reference subnets /subscriptions
>   /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter/providers/Microsoft.Netwo
>   rk/virtualNetworks/confvnet/subnets/confclustersubnet,/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroup
>   s/resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/conf-virtual-network-interlink/s
>   ubnets/default from different virtual networks. ErrorTarget:
>   StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request OperationID :
>   ebdcd379-2dba-4a2d-97a8-52c7870a8755 In
>   X:\JIRA_Confluence_Migration\PowerShell\network-interfaces-azure.ps1:49
>   Zeichen:1
>   + Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira- ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureRmVmss], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.UpdateAzureRmVmss

But my intention actually is to add two different network adapters from the different virtual networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know you cannot have different network adapters in different virtual networks. they have to be on the same virtual network, they can be on a different subnet in the same virtual network

Comment: if this answer helped you - consider accepting it ;)